# RoR Rails 3 Devise::SessionsController fails to authenticate existing user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, device

- I'm starting the app at http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
- accept user / password; posting
- device fails to authenticate my user and jumps into #new
- #new render sign_in again, so I am in a loop.

**here is the log:**

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-30 17:49:33 -0700
      Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NhVu4CQwhatever+CAErP19YVIkz0lIz3qEERac=", "user"=>{"email"=>"abc@def.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
```

Then it runs the SQL to fetch the user. copy/pate to postgresql, the 'select' fetch my user record. it definitely exists**

```
[1m[35mUser Load (5.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'abc@def.com' LIMIT 1
```

The next log entry: jumps to #new - as if the user do not exist

```
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NhVu4CQwhatever+CAErP19YVIkz0lIz3qEERac=", "user"=>{"email"=>"abc@def.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
    Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms)
```

Comment: perhaps an authentication error? does the <%= alert %> say anything?

Comment: No alerts and no message coming from the long list at device.en.yml